# How to export Hive table to CSV with all fields escaped

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

How to export Hive table in a format like this:

```
"aaa,aaa","bbbbbb","cccccc"
```

I already tired:

1) Create a temp table based on initial one with `"row format ... escaped by '\042'"`

2) Use `"insert overwrite  ... row format ... escaped by '\042'"`

Both escape only fields containing some special characters, like this:

```
"aaa,aaa",bbbbbb,cccccc
```

I have Hive version 1.1.0-cdh5.5.0

Comment: which version of hive are you using?  have you tried the csv serde?

Comment: @shainnif I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Hive 0.14 and greater, you can use [CSV Serde](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde)

You can specify the serde properties like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(a string, b string, ...)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "\t",
   "quoteChar"     = "'",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
)  
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```